# AirPlay, Chromecast, Miracast SDK

Tags: sdk, chromecast, airplay, miracast

I would like to realize an Android application that would be able to **display an AirPlay, Miracast or Chromecast** stream.

This application will be a **basic Viewer** of these 3 technologies.

I would like that when you launch it, you can see it on your iPhone, Android or Windows Phone or even from computers (PC or Mac). So you can project your screen on an Android.

I've seen some apps on the Play Store that were able to show AirPlay or Google Cast streams but I have not found them for Miracast.

Do you have links to send me **SDK** of these 3 technologies ?

Thank you all !